# Syntax for specifying a method reference to a generic method

Tags: java, generics, method-reference

I read the following code in "Java - The beginner's guide"

```
interface SomeTest <T>
{
    boolean test(T n, T m);
}

class MyClass
{
    static <T> boolean myGenMeth(T x, T y)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        // ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

The following statement is valid

```
SomeTest <Integer> mRef = MyClass :: <Integer> myGenMeth;
```

Two points were made regarding the explanation of the above code

> 1 - When a generic method is specified as a method reference, its type argument comes after the `::` and before the method name.
>
> 2 - In case in which a generic class is specified, the type argument follows the class name and precedes the `::`.

#### My query:-

The code above is the example of the first quoted point

Can someone provide me an example of code which implement the second quoted point?

(Basically I don't understand the second quoted point).

Comment: This code does not compile.

Comment: @ChetanKinger : This code will not compile as it is. First you have to add a main class in it and then put `SomeTest <Integer> mRef = MyClass :: <Integer> myGenMeth;` in that main class

Comment: Please post [MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code sample. As far I know, it won't compile even after we do what you said in the previous comment.

Comment: @kevingomes, unfortunately the accepted answer from Keppil is probably still not correct in the context of your actual question. While that is one form of method reference, it probably isn't what the book means in that quote.

Comment: @AndyBrown :please post the correct answer then.

Comment: @kevingomes. I was about to, but noticed that bayou.io already did.

Comment: @AndyBrown : Can you please tell me the difference between both the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second quoted point just means that the type parameter belongs to the class. For example:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    public boolean myGenMeth(T x, T y)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        // ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

This would then be called like this:

```
SomeTest<Integer> mRef = new MyClass<Integer>() :: myGenMeth;
```

Comment: why can't I add `static` before `boolean myGenMeth(T x, T y);`

Comment: `static` would turn the method into a _class method_ instead of an _instance method_. Since you have to create an instance of the class to set the type parameter here, you can't declare a `static` method that uses the generic class type parameter.

Comment: dude, your code isn't working; I used `SomeTest <Integer> mRef = MyClass <Integer> :: genMeth;`

Comment: @kevingomes It won't work because you don't have `OtherClass`. Keppil was hyst giving you an example. Change it to `Integer` :)

Comment: @ChetanKinger : I am using `Integer`, still it is not working

Comment: @ChetanKinger @keppil : Giving error in every case : `Non static method myGenMeth <T,T> can not be referenced from a static context`

Comment: @kevin: Fixed the calling part.

Comment: great effort. But please include the difference between your current answer and your previous answer. Why it was not working as per your previous answer?

Comment: The mistake I made was not remembering to create an instance of the class to use when referencing the method. I even touched on it in my comment above, but didn't see the error in the code I posted. My bad.

Comment: @kevingomes You really need to make up your mind about what your question is. Are you asking *Why does my code not compile*?

Comment: @ChetanKinger : Read my question carefully. I, in very simple words, asked the meaning of the `second quoted point` in my question.

Comment: @kevingomes but does point 1 even compile? I don't have Java -8 here on my machine to confirm this.

Comment: @ChetanKinger : Yes, just add, `class Main{ public static void main(String args[]) {  SomeTest <Integer> mRef = MyClass :: <Integer> myGenMeth;} }`

Comment: @ChetanKinger : Now you came to the point. This feature is only supported in java-8

Comment: @kevingomes Lol. I know it's only available in `Java-8`. What I am asking is does it compile in `Java-8`. Nevermind though. If it compiles for you then i am fine with it :)

Comment: @Keppil : Can you please tell me the difference between your answer and   bayou.io's answer

Answer (score 2):

For example

```
  Predicate<List<String>> p = List<String>::isEmpty;
```

Actually we don't need the type argument here; the type inference will take care of

```
  Predicate<List<String>> p = List::isEmpty;
```

But in cases type inference fails, e.g. when passing this method reference to a generic method without enough constraints for inference, it might be necessary to specify the type arguments.

Comment: can you please tell me the difference between your answer and Keppil's answer

Comment: [@Keppil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31245276/581002) unnecessarily constructs an instance of `MyClass`.