# Difference between the two method references to instance methods

Tags: java, method-reference

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.*;

interface SomeTest <T>
{
    boolean test(T n, T m);
}

class MyClass <T>
{
    boolean myGenMeth(T x, T y)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        // ...
        return result;
    }
}

class Timepass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SomeTest <Integer> mRef = MyClass <Integer> :: myGenMeth;   //Statement 1

        Predicate <List<String>> p = List<String> :: isEmpty;       //Statement 2
    }
}
```

#### My query

In the above code, `Statement 1` produces two compile time errors

> 1- Can not find method `myGenMeth(Integer, Integer)`
>
> 2- Non static method `myGenMeth(T, T)` can not be referenced from static context

Where as, `Statement 2` shows no error.

1- ***What is the difference between `Statement 1` and `Statement 2`??***

#### 2- How the `Statement 2` is working fine.

#### (I am not asking why the `Statement 1` is producing error).

Comment: Both questions have already been answered in the [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245127/syntax-for-specifying-a-method-reference-to-a-generic-method) question that you asked. Quit posting duplicates.

Comment: Both questions are different. And the difference is easily noticable.

Comment: The accepted answer to your previous question already explains the reason for statement 1 resulting in a compilation error (See the comments section if you have a short term memory ;) )

Comment: @ChetanKinger : You are right, but my question is why the second statement is not producing error

Comment: That has also been answered in your previous question.

Comment: @ChetanKinger : Stop arguing about the question, If you find the answer, then please post the answer

Comment: I am not arguing. Just keeping the site clean. Edit your question and remove parts that are not required.

Comment: @ChetanKinger : Time and again you are just asking me to edit my question, without answering it. Just read the two last points in my question, and if you have their answer, please post.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question and removing the part that has already been answered.

Comment: @ChetanKinger : Now i expect a satisfactory answer

Comment: @ChetanKinger : add `import java.util.function.*;` Then it will compile

Answer (score 1):

Because you have method references to instance methods, but don't specify any specific instance, the instance needs to be passed as a parameter to the interface method.

For statement 2, you can pass this instance to the `test` method of `Predicate`:

```
p.test(new ArrayList<>());
```

But for statement 1, `test` doesn't take an instance as a parameter:

```
mRef.test(new MyClass<>(), 1, 2);
```

To make this compile, `SomeTest` needs to be changed to:

```
interface SomeTest<T> {
    boolean test(MyClass<T> instance, T n, T m);
}
```

Alternatively, you can make the method references refer to specific instances, then the interface method doesn't need to contain that parameter:

```
SomeTest <Integer> mRef = new MyClass<Integer>()::myGenMeth;
mRef.test(1, 2);

Supplier<Boolean> p = new ArrayList<>()::isEmpty;
p.get();
```