# Generic method reference type specifying before/after :: operator

Tags: java, generics, java-8, method-reference

What is the difference between the following method references,

```
BiPredicate<List<String>,String> contains1 = List<String>::contains;

BiPredicate<List<String>,String> contains2 = List::<String>contains;

BiPredicate<List<String>,String> contains3 = List<String>::<String>contains;
```

Do the cases have special names? Is there any example similar to the usage?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245127/syntax-for-specifying-a-method-reference-to-a-generic-method. Seems the first syntax specifies type argument for `List`, whereas the second specifies type argument for `contains` (unnecessary in this case because the method is not generic)

Comment: And, of course, `BiPredicate<List<String>,String> contains1 = List<String>::<String>contains;`.

Comment: As a related side-note, and a partial explanation: it's legal to supply type arguments to a non-generic method, such as [`list.<Number>contains("foo")`](https://ideone.com/13s46Y). They're just ignored. (As for why the JLS authors chose to allow it, though, I don't know.)

Comment: @Radiodef I don't know its exact reason but I suspect that you are _**Herbert Schildt**_

Comment: @Radiodef by the way, it is really interesting, [`list.<RandomAccess>contains("foo");`](https://ideone.com/chRhxV) and [`list.<ClassLoader>contains("foo");`](https://ideone.com/chRhxV)

Comment: @snr Why is it legal to supply type arguments to a non-generic method? You can find the answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014853/what-is-the-point-of-allowing-type-witnesses-on-all-method-calls/28127212)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, that is called a *type witness* ([in the official Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)) or *TypeArguments* (in the [JLS Sec 15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12))  and you are effectively helping the compiler with such constructs.

One example:

```
private static void test(Callable<Object> call) {

}

private static void test(Runnable run) {

}

static class Gen<T> {

}
```

And call it via `test(Gen::new);` (this will fail, never mind why), but the point is that you add a *type witness* to help the compiler, so this would work

```
test(Gen<String>::new);
```

So when you write `List<String>`, you have added a type witness for the target type - `List` that is; in the second case you are adding one for the method `contains` - but it's not generic, so it is ignored.

Comment: Where does the term "type witness" come from? I can't find it in the language spec.

Comment: @AndyTurner https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html search for "type witness", I was not saying it's in the `JLS` (might be, not sure)

Comment: @Lino the official java tutorial calls it that way, I'll stick to that :)

Comment: The word "witness" doesn't appear in JLS (9, at least). They are simply called `TypeArguments` there.

Answer (score 5):

In:

```
BiPredicate<List<String>, String> contains2 = List::<String>contains;
```

`<String>` is a type argument to a non-generic `List.contains` method<sup>1</sup>.

While in:

```
BiPredicate<List<String>, String> contains1 = List<String>::contains;
```

`<String>` is a type argument to a `List`.

---

<sup>1 - In this particular case a type argument is ignored according to the [JLS §15.12.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1):</sup>

> <sup>A non-generic method may be potentially applicable to an invocation
>   that supplies explicit type arguments. In such a case, the type
>   arguments will simply be ignored.</sup>

Comment: Is there any difference btw _type parameter_ and _type argument_ terms in this context? If yes, what is this?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. `E` in `List<E>` is a type parameter and the `String` in `List<String>` is a type argument. You can think of a generic type invocation as being similar to an ordinary method invocation, but instead of passing an argument to a method, you are passing a type argument - `String` in this case - to the `List` itself [(source).](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Answer (score 4):

Here's what Intellij tells me about them:

```
BiPredicate<List<String>, String> contains1 = List<String>::contains;
```

> Explicit type arguments can be inferred

```
BiPredicate<List<String>, String> contains2 = List::<String>contains;
```

> Type arguments are redundant for the non-generic method reference

If you were to split these up into their respective lambda functions, I believe you'd see the following:

```
BiPredicate<List<String>, String> contains1 = (List<String> strings, String o) -> strings.contains(o);
BiPredicate<List<String>, String> contains2 = (strings, o) -> strings.<String>contains(o);
```

As we know, `(List<String> strings, String o)` can be replaced by `(strings, o)` and `<String>` on the second line is unneeded (as `String#contains` isn't generic), so it's safe to assume that both method references are equivalent.